# How to center the infobubble when marker is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im using the infobubble from googlemaps api V3.

I have an event which is on my markers and each time it gets clicked I get a bubble.

I used infobox and infowindow before and they always positioned themselves in the center of the map when i clicked on the marker, if my knowledge of them both is correct then this was accomplished by the pixelOffset property.

Infobubble however does not give me the same effect, i get this:

[image]

My code:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     $.ajax({
        url: '/templates/GoogleMapsMarkerInfo.aspx?id=' + page + '&epslanguage=<%=CurrentPage.LanguageBranch %>',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){


                      var myOptions = {

                      content: data,
                      maxWidth: 300,
                      shadowStyle: 1,
                      padding: 0,
                      backgroundColor: '#fff',
                      borderRadius: 15,
                      arrowSize: 7,
                      borderWidth: 1,
                      borderColor: 'blue',
                      disableAutoPan: true,
                      hideCloseButton: false,
                      arrowPosition: 25,
                      backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
                      arrowStyle: 2

                };

                            if(infoBubble.getContent()!="")
            infoBubble.close()
            infoBubble.setOptions(myOptions)
            infoBubble.open(map, marker);

        }
     });
```

To clarify:
I wan't the bubble to get centerd on the map so that the entire information is shown, I don't want to be forced to drag on the map to see the entire bubble.

If more info is needed ask and i will do my best to provide it.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to sign the question, we can see your name at the bottom already ;)

Comment: Just a habbit i guess, will try to remember that.

Comment: at a guess, the problem might be `disableAutoPan: true,`  - remove this or set it to false and see what happens

Comment: Well im a bit embaressed to say but this actually did the trick. 

i was googling for hours to find properties that i did not have instead of analyzing the ones i had in further detail.

thanks duncan! would be cool if you could add this as an aswer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Only set `disableAutoPan` to `False`.